# How do I get jQueryUI's 'dialog' widget to use the `ui-state-error` styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using one of the standard themes (redmond) provided on the jQuery UI website.

I noticed that it ships with an icon png file with red icons as well as the blue coloured ones. I need to display a warning dialog box but make it use the red icons instead.

I notice in the theme's stylesheet there's a section called "Interaction Cues". Do I just set my `dialogClass` to `ui-state-error` which seems to have the desired effect, is this the correct way to do this?

I tried setting `dialogClass: "error"` but that had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep you have it right, you need the full class name:

```
$("div").dialog({ dialogClass: "ui-state-error" });
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/EDFPz/).